# Grep in file for good or wrong result and export those to values

Tags: bash, perl, if-statement, awk, sed

I have file with positive and negative values.

Want to export variable if everything is different from `STATE_ACTIVE` to be `w1=STATE_INACTIVE` if everything is `STATE_ACTIVE` to be `w1=STATE_ACTIVE`

```
STATE_ACTIVE
STATE_ACTIVE
STATE_INACTIVE
STATE_ACTIVE
```

I try with if operators but cannot able to catch the whole file values.

Comment: `"STATE_ACTIVE" to be w1=STATE_INACTIVE if everything is "STATE_ACTIVE" to be w1=STATE_ACTIVE` unclear for me. Could you post an expected output?

Comment: I mean when grep the whole file there state which every time should be STATE_ACTIVE but if some row have different of that state to turn negative value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep has a useful feature - `$?` is set based on whether it found anything or not.

```
grep -vq 'STATE_ACTIVE' myfile
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
  export w1=STATE_INACTIVE
else
  export w1=STATE_ACTIVE
fi
```

Comment: `if [ $? ]` will not do what you want it to. That will always be true. You want `if grep -v STATE_INACTIVE myfile` to test the return code of `grep` (or whatever command).

Comment: not every time STATE_INACTIVE is the only different value for that reason I want everything which is differen from STATE_ACTIVE to have negative value

Comment: OK. `grep -v STATE_ACTIVE` will test if there's anything that _isn't_ STATE active. (amended the test line as well).

Answer (score 0):

just `grep -q 'STATE_INACTIVE'` then read return code: `$?` if not zero, it means `no INACTIVE` found. otherwise, `INACTIVE` was hit.

`-q` makes grep don't output things.

Comment: The Idea is not every time exist that STATE_INACTIVE could be also STATE_SUSSPEND or anything else

Comment: `grep -v` is good for negative matches.

Comment: @KalinBorisov it is ok if you have problem to code/implement something. but if you came to ask help, please make your question clear...

Comment: @Sobrique I don't see what effort can be saved by `-v`

Comment: Surely it's exactly what you need if you've got an exclusion match? E.g. anything that's not 'STATE_ACTIVE'.

Comment: @Sobrique I don't know what he wants, to be honest.... `I have file with positive and negative values` then `STATE_SUSSPEND`...